# What RegEx to select comma separated CSS selectors individually in SublimeText?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

The other day I had to prefix every single CSS selector with another tag in order to increase its specificity. I though I'd flex my regex muscles a bit and I came up with this regex:

`(^(((\s)+)?(?!.+: )(?!\.IE)[a-z.].+?)([,{]))`

The plan was to replace the entire captured match with something like 'body $1'. There are a couple of negative lookaheads to avoid matching lines like `background-color:` property and .IE selectors

The screenshot describes the problem:

[image]

Here is some sample text:

```
/* line 18, ../scss/SplashPage/_page.scss */
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}


/* line 35, ../scss/SplashPage/_page.scss */
body header {
  *zoom: 1;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
/* line 221, ../scss/MainStyle/_mixins.scss */
body header:before, body header:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}
/* line 224, ../scss/MainStyle/_mixins.scss */
body header:after {
  clear: both;
}
body .utility-nav {
  right:0
}
/* line 40, ../scss/SplashPage/_page.scss */
body .home-link {
  text-indent: -99999px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent url("~/images/clipsal-logo2.png") center center no-repeat;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url("~/images/clipsal-logo.svg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url("~/images/clipsal-logo.svg");
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  /*width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px 0px 15px 25px;*/
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

I think it's the start of line anchor (^) that needs do be dropped. Having said that I am not sure what the regex should be :)

Note: I understand that the problem could have easily been solved using SASS, but where's the fun in that!

Thanks

Comment: "*I had to prefix every single CSS selector with another tag*". This seems something you shouldn't have had to do.

Comment: @Oriol yep, due to reasons beyond my control the order in which the css files were referenced had to be changed (reversed) and this particular css  ,let's call it 'newcss', was overriding the rules on the previous one, let's call it 'oldcss'. Once the ordering was changed, 'oldcss' was not overriding rules defined in the 'newcss' file. Hope that makes sense. Do you see another way to solve the problem, besides making the rules on 'newcss' stronger in terms of specificity?

Comment: This is not a masterwork regex.  Use the new class that you want to add in the regex to exclude ones that are already changed, run search and replace many times.